# Eliminate Classification Head in Mask R-CNN

Tags: detectron, mask-rcnn

Is it possible to remove the classification head in Mask R-CNN.
Despite enabling class-agnostic settings for both bounding box regression and mask prediction, I am still observing classification loss during training. This seems to suggest that the classification head is still active, even though I have attempted to disable it.

I have set the following configurations in my code:

```
# Whether to use class agnostic for bbox regression
cfg.MODEL.ROI_BOX_HEAD.CLS_AGNOSTIC_BBOX_REG = True
# Whether to use class agnostic for mask prediction
cfg.MODEL.ROI_MASK_HEAD.CLS_AGNOSTIC_MASK = True
```

I would appreciate any guidance on how to completely eliminate the classification head in Mask R-CNN. Alternatively, if there are any additional configurations or modifications I need to make, please let me know.

Thank you for your support.